# Extract text from html string using Jsoup with specific encoding

Tags: java, string, jsoup, iso-8859-1

Here is what I have -

```
String html = "<p><b>Annie's and Lärabar</b></p>"
```

after run the following -

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
Element p= doc.select("p").first();
String s = p.text();
System.out.println(s);
```

output - `"Annie's and L?rabar".`

The character "ä" became a question mark.

My JVM environment is "iso-8859-1", it seems to me that Jsoup's default encoding is utf-8.  I would like to force Jsoup.parse() to use "iso-8859-1" when parsing the html string.

I read the API and googled examples, but I just can't find any single one example which indicates that Jsoup.parse() can actually take in a specific encoding when parsing a string?

Can anyone help?  Thank you in advance!

-Cyn

Comment: Why do you think that problem root is `Jsoup` encoding?
Will be umlauts printed correctly if you print original HTML, e.g. `System.out.println(html);`?

Comment: Because I traced the code.  The character was correctly displayed until the after the line "org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);"

Comment: Did `System.out.println(html);` print the word `Lärabar` *to console* correctly?
If `html` variable content not printed correctly then obviously problem is not with `Jsoup`.
There may be problem with console encoding you output to. Try to redirect program output to the file and open this file in text editor as an UTF8-encoded text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set char set to Document as below

```
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
doc.charset(Charset charset);
Element p= doc.select("p").first();
String s = p.text();
```

Hope this help.
Refer: https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Document.html#charset-java.nio.charset.Charset-

Comment: Hi AG_, thanks for your reply!  I tried to set the charset, but just by typing doc.charset in my IDE I got an syntax error.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Comment: You have to pass the charset as argument, eg. `doc.charset(Charset.forName("charset name here"));`.

Comment: in you case : doc.charset(Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1")); and import java.nio.charset.Charset

Comment: Maybe we are using different version of Jsoup?  I solved the issue by adding this line after creating the Document and before doing Element select - doc.outputSettings().escapeMode(Entities.EscapeMode.xhtml);.  It worked.  Thanks!